# Python crashes when trying to start Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I just installed the Anaconda package (64 bit, python 2.7) on my Windows 10.
Python itself works fine. The programmed code gets executed fine.
However, when I try to run the Anaconda Navigator or try to run conda command in the windows prompt python crashes.
A windows error pops up, telling me "Python has stopped working".

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this? I tried to reinstall the Anaconda package, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally uninstalling Anaconda might break the newer installations.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222653/anaconda-navigator-wont-open-tried-all-other-threads/55223846#55223846), it help me solve similar issues with missing Anaconda Navigator and broken anaconda installations after an uninstallation.

Hope it helps you. :)

**EDIT**

The version of new packages should be the same with the base Miniconda.

For **Python2** do `conda install anaconda=5.3.1=py27_0 anaconda-navigator=1.9.6=py27_0`.

The important thing to specify the **Python 2.7** build.

You can search more information about packages with the `conda show <package>` command for versions and builds.