# Anaconda Navigator Won't Open - Tried all other threads

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Uninstalled Anaconda Navigator last week and now it wont work once I've reinstalled it.

Windows search doesn't find an anaconda navigator program but in C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-navigator-1.9.2-py37_0\Scripts, there is a anaconda navigator application. When i open this, a command prompt box flashes and vanishes within 0.5 secs.

`C:\Users\admin>where conda`

Returns `'where is not a recognized internal or external command'`

`conda update` has same response as well as all other 'conda' calls

Have uninstalled and ticked (and also unticked) the PATH option numerous times for both and hasn't worked. Have also tried clearing the PATH in the advanced section.

Basically, I've tried all the other suggestions on SO and cant find anything which works.

Edit: Calling python in the command prompt does work too - so python works but none of the anaconda options including spyder, jupyter etc etc. (RStudio does work in my computer though)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact thing happened to me the yesterday.

1. Uninstall the new anaconda installation.
2. Delete all the conda, anaconda files and folders on your computer. (They are located inside the `C:\Users\<yourusername>`, `C:\Users\<yourusername>\Appdata\Local` and `C:\Users\<yourusername>\Appdata\Roaming` folders).
3. Restart your computer.
4. Download the appropriate Miniconda installer.

> The fix is in the latest Miniconda installers:
>
> 64-bit:
>   https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe
>
> https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe
>
> 32-bit:
>
> https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86.exe
>
> https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Windows-x86.exe
>
> [source](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6053#issuecomment-354473217)

5. Install it using the suggested settings.
6. Run the start menu shorcut `Anaconda Prompt`.
7. Execute the command `conda install anaconda anaconda-navigator`.

Hopefully this will solve your issues (it solved mine).

*I would suggest against having Anaconda in your `PATH` because it is designed to run inside an environment and having it run separately (outside the environment) might mess things up.*

Comment: You beauty. I spent so much time on this and nothing else worked until now. Thank you

Comment: My Anaconda stopped working after messing around with QtDesigner and I've been trying to solve this issue for hours. Just stumbled upon this answer, and it's the only one that works. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve the issue by doing the following:

1. Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 - 2019 redistributable (x64) - 14.25. 28508
2. Add file: msvcp140.dll (follow tutorial in youtube)
3. Add file: msvcp140_1.dll

Comment: How does this answer the question?