# Anaconda unable to initialize

Tags: python, anaconda

Currently whenever i try to open the -conda application or anaconda navigator application file, a python programming window pops up for 1 second then immediately crashes. I've reinstalled anaconda 5 times but it just won't open. Additionally, whenever i download anaconda, it doesn't create any anaconda navigator or anaconda prompt shortcuts, so i have to travel to the file location itself and try to open the application files to try and open anaconda but it still doesn't work.

When i entered `anaconda-navigator` into cmd, it says it doesn't recognise anaconda-navigator at all.
I'm running windows 10 and downloaded the latest anaconda version for it but it just doesn't seem to open after i download it. 
However i'm able to open the python 3.7 application within the anaconda folder, but nothing else works.

Comment: Don't directly click on anaconda navigator file, instead run the same file from command prompt and check for error.

Comment: _I've reinstalled anaconda 5 times but it just won't open._ How are you installing it? _Currently whenever i try to open the -conda application_ Can you be more specific? Open how? _When i entered `anaconda-navigator` into cmd, it says it doesn't recognise anaconda-navigator at all._ Can you run Conda from CMD, though?

Comment: When i try to run anaconda navigator into command prompt it says that it doesn't recognise it/doesn't exist. Also i've been installing it directly from the website lately and when i try to open conda either directly by clicking on the application or entering -conda into command prompt, only a commands window pops up for a slight second then dissapears. I tried the solution here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222653/anaconda-navigator-wont-open-tried-all-other-threads/55223846#55223846 but it didn't work for me.